# Complete 11.04 desktop customization guide

Tags: 11.04, unity, customization

Are there any comprehensive desktop customization guide for 11.04 for novices like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/unity-personalization-how-much-can-you-really-do/) on [OMG!Ubuntu!](http://omgubuntu.co.uk) talks about customising Unity, the default interface for 11.04. It is an interesting read and should place you in the right direction for customising Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/things-to-tweak-fix-after-installing.html is one of the better ones for Unity. It includes all of the places I've been able to find with different settings, and a lot of cool tips.